# Censoring sensitive data on Google DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, sensitive-data

On Google dialog flow, is there a way to censor sensitive data. Suppose the user enters his credit card data, is there way to either have ** in place of the credit number, or the entire sentence? I tried sending a HTTP patch request 
 as per https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents/patch, unsuccessfully. I dont understand what this is doing, if after succeeding we want to revert, how do we do that? Is there a better way to handle this problem?

Comment: is the idea to mask it for Google not to log it on Dialogflow, or do you want to mask it before it leave your server

Comment: For google not to log it in Dialogflow. For example, if the customer asks for his atm pin, he should be able to hear it, but the number should not show on the logs of google

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. So you will have to do it before sending it over to the cloud service as far as i know. If you know what you are looking for it can be quite straightforward, but if you look for general PII data, it is super difficult on the server side. Microsoft released something interesting - https://medium.com/microsoftazure/protecting-personal-identifiable-information-with-azure-ai-aa4b7afc4839, but you need to be confortable with the transcient aspect of the solution

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check it out!